# Convert BW Image to Matrix

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, type-conversion, data-conversion

After converting an image `x` to a black and white image by using `im2bw(x)`, `imfilter` returns black and white images only. How can I convert this black and white image into a normal matrix such that `imfilter` can return a matrix of reals? Demo:

```
>> k = [0.3 0.3; 0   0.3];
>> x = [0.9 0.3; 0.4 0.2];
>> y = im2bw(x)
y =

  1 0
  0 0
>> imfilter(y, k)
ans = 

  1  0
  0  0
>> imfilter([1 0; 0 0], k)
ans =

  0.30000  0.00000
  0.00000  0.00000
>>
```

As you can see, `imfilter` rounds the results when applying to a binary image. I would like to prevent this. How can I convert the binary image to a regular matrix while keeping its values?

Comment: have you tried `y = double(y)`?

Comment: @beaker Nope - and it works. I will accept this if you add it as an answer. I can't believe how long I spent googling and how simply the answer is... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`imfilter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html?s_tid=doc_ta),

> The result B has the same size and class as A.

Since the output from `im2bw` is a logical array, the output of `imfilter` is too. In order to get a floating-point output from `imfilter` you need to cast the thresholded image to a float type:

```
y = double(y);   % or, y = single(y);
```

Result:

```
>> k = [0.3 0.3; 0   0.3];
>> x = [0.9 0.3; 0.4 0.2];
>> y = im2bw(x)
y =

  1  0
  0  0

>> y = double(y)
y =

   1   0
   0   0

>> imfilter(y, k)
ans =

   0.30000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000
```